# how to reach assets path with nginx and vite

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vite

I use nginx and vite to docker vue.js.
However, when I set the base path, the browser screen goes blank.
The /test/index html is returned, but the /test/assets/something.js and css also return html.
How can I rewrite the vite + base + nginx so that the following URLs are displayed correctly?

htttp://localhost:808/test/index

vite.confign.ts

```
base: '/test/',
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen   8080 default_server;
    server_name  "";

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    location ~ ^/assets/(.*)$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        root /home/vue_server/assets/$1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        root /home/vue_server/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    # Include MIME types file if not defined previously
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    location /test/ {
        alias /home/vue_server/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 /test/$uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried it but the screen remained blank.

Comment: do you see trafic?, check logs for errors: ´tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log´

Comment: please test the new config

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried it but the behavior did not change.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked.
Thank you very much.